# custom listadapter for fragment

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a custom list adapter, but it says that I can't use

```
ListFragment.setListAdapter(cafeItemArrayAdapter);
```

Because: non-static method cannot be referred from a static context.

This is my .java file

```
package swinnen.jente.mijnapp;

/**
 * Created by jenteswinnen on 10/01/16.
 */
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import Model.Cafe;


public class TwoFragment extends ListFragment {

    ArrayAdapter cafeItemArrayAdapter;

    public TwoFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);

        cafeItemArrayAdapter = new CafeAdapter(this, cafes);
        ListFragment.setListAdapter(cafeItemArrayAdapter);

    }
```

and this is my adapter:

```
package swinnen.jente.mijnapp;


import Model.Cafe;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;
/**
 * Created by jenteswinnen on 10/01/16.
 */
public class CafeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cafe> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public CafeAdapter(Fragment activity, List<Cafe> items){
        super(activity.getActivity(), R.layout.row_cafe, items);
        inflater = activity.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_cafe, parent, false);

        Cafe myObject = getItem(position);

        TextView titel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cafeNaam);
        titel.setText(myObject.getNaam());
        TextView email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email);
        email.setText(myObject.getEmail());
        TextView openings = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.openings);
        openings.setText(myObject.getEmail());
        return view;


    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `ListFragment` word on that line of code, so it should look like this:

```
setListAdapter(cafeItemArrayAdapter);
```

What you were doing was accesing the method of the class `ListFragment` instead of an instance of it.

Furthermore, this code will be unreachable if you put it after a return statement, so put it before:

```
    cafeItemArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.activity_main);
    setListAdapter(cafeItemArrayAdapter);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
```